# how GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread() works? how to get used memory by a thread?

Tags: c#, memory, .net-core, garbage-collection, profile

I need a method to profile and log the amount of memory used by a thread in a .net core project.
I found this interesting method: GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread();

As method name says I expect to get the amount of bytes used by the thread, but I get instead extremely high values like: 26111439440 bytes and that is not possible since doesn't match the used memory on task manager and the available memory on my machine.

Do you know another method compatible with .net core 2.0 that accomplish my purpose?

> **UPDATE**:

<s>`GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread()` is bugged, there is no way the value that returns have meaning.</s>

I dunno if related but there was already a bug (now closed) related similar to my situation: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10207
I reported there.

`GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread()` Returns the cumulative memory used by the thread, not the amount current used, so if thread continue to allocate and deallocate memory, the function can return very highs values even if you have never used so much memory at same time

> **WORKAROUND**:

There is no way to get the reliable memory used by the thread, but you can get the memory used by the process:

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long memory = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```

If you calculate the memory before start the thread and after you can estimate the memory used by that.

Comment: Sounds like a question for github and smells very bug like

Comment: @TheGeneral do you think it's a bug? Yeah maybe I try to post on github.
But my question remains valid in case exist another way to get used memory.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A thread has its own stack space and that is certainly used by the thread in that it isn't shared. In addition to that a thread can create objects which are then placed on the shared heap. However, objects may be shared by other threads, so determining usage gets tricky.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I need to optimize a library, so I create a logger that at every iteration logs the used memory by the thread, but values are not realistic.
I don't need precise memory usage, but it's impossible that I use 26 Gib of memory.

Comment: maybe it's a bug, I found this on github: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/10207

The issue in my case appear with xunit like is reported on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread` returns the cumulative total of bytes allocated by the current thread, even if those allocations have already been cleaned up by the garbage collector. It does not return the current amount of in-use memory. For that, you can use `Process.WorkingSet64` or `Process.PrivateMemorySize64`, depending on what you're trying to measure.

26111439440 is only 24.3 GiB, which seems quite reasonable for a memory-hungry program to have allocated during its lifetime.

Comment: I still investigating because I feel weird to use so much ram, but your is a good and clean explanation of how GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread  works, so I accept your answer.